# Can we filter Datatable with LINQ?

Tags: linq

Suppose my datatable is filled with data. 
After filling data can we again put some condition on datatable with linq to extract data.

Suppose my datatable has 10 employee record. 
So can we extract only those employee whose salary is greater than 5000 with linq query. 
I know that we can achieve it `datatable.select()`. How can you achieve this with `linq`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get a filtered set of rows, yes:

```
var query = table.AsEnumerable()
                 .Where(row => row.Field<decimal>("salary") > 5000m);
```

This uses the `AsEnumerable` and `Field` extension methods in [`DataTableExtensions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.aspx) and [`DataRowExtensions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowextensions.aspx) respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
                var query = (from t0 in dtDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                where t0.Field<string>("FieldName") == Filter

               select new
               {
                   FieldName  = t0.Field<string>("FieldName"),
                   FieldName2 = t0.Field<string>("FieldName2"),
                });
```